# How to define formula dynamically from select input ( multiple = TRUE) in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, linear-regression

I am trying to define a formula for multinomial logistic regression , it should take the input from drop down list upto maximum 6 Independent variables. ( SelectInput , Multiple = TRUE) in R Shiny. Not able to figure out how to resolve this ..

Here are sample code... 
Formula

`Multiformula <- reactive ({
as.formula(paste(input$outcome,'~'input$predictor)
})`

Model

```
MultiModel <- reactive({
    multinom(Multiformula(), data = filtered())
  })
```

Above code works for single variable, however  for more than one independent variables the approach may be different. I tried the below but no luck

```
indvar6 <- reactive({
  filter(forest_data_model[,input$predictor])
  })
```

Redefined  the formula... but it didn't work

```
Multiformula <- reactive ({as.formula(paste(input$outcome,'~'indvar6())})
```

Any guidance will be highly appreciated...thanks

Comment: Try `as.formula(paste(input$outcome,'~', paste(input$predictor, collapse = "+")))`

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick solution...working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could try

```
library(shiny)
library(nnet)
library(foreign)
fmnom <- function(data  = NULL, depVar, indepVar) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    headerPanel("Multinomial analysis"), 
    sidebarPanel(
      p("Select inputs for the Dependent Variable"),
      selectInput(inputId = "dep", label = "Dependent Variables", multiple = FALSE, 
                       choices = as.list(depVar)),
      p("Select input for the Independent Variable"),
      selectInput(inputId = "indep", label = "Independent Variables", 
                  multiple = TRUE, choices = as.list(indepVar), selected = indepVar[1])
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "RegOut"),
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "IndPrint"),
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "DepPrint")

    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {

    mlt <- reactive(
                     {multinom(reformulate(input$indep, input$dep), data = data)})

    output$DepPrint <- renderPrint({input$dep})
    output$IndPrint <- renderPrint({input$indep})
    output$RegOut <- renderPrint({summary(mlt())})

  }



  shinyApp(ui= ui, server = server)
}
```

-data

```
ml <- read.dta("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta")
```

-run shiny

```
fmnom(ml, depVar = c("prog", "schtyp"), indepVar = c("ses", "read", "write") )
```

-output single independent variable

[image]

-output multiple independent variables

[image]

Comment: Can we plot effect plot for the selected variables ? I am using  below code for one predictor                                                                          output$plot <- renderPlot({ 
        plot <-effect(input$predictor, model())
        plot(plot,style = "stacked", rug = FALSE,ci.style="bands",show.strip.values=TRUE,
             show.fitted=TRUE,multiline=TRUE)
      })

Comment: @nab Could you please post as a new question as it is not clear to me

Comment: Sure I am posting a new question

Comment: @nab Thanks, the reason I didn't quite folllow what you want from that comments

Comment: Got the solution. I was referring to effects plot for the coefficients. I have used below code for the same                                                 output$plot <- renderPlot({ 
        
        eff_plot <- allEffects(model())
        
        plot(eff_plot,style = "stacked", rug = FALSE,ci.style="bands",show.strip.values=TRUE,
              show.fitted=TRUE,multiline=TRUE)
        
      })